# Merge Statement for more than hundreds of columns

Tags: sql

I have a `Source` and `Target` table that contain more than 150 columns, actually the problem is I need to compare, and insert this 150 column in my `MERGE` statement, is there any other way to do this?

```
MERGE targettable AS [Target]
USING ( 
       ---Source Query*
      ) AS [Source] ON [Target].Key = [Source].Key

WHEN MATCHED  --Matching records with change //Update 
     AND [Target].[StartDt] <> [Source].[StartDt]  
      OR [Target].[ADStatusDesc] <> [Source].[ADStatusDesc] 
      ..... --more than 150 columns
     OR [Target].[StatusInd] <> [Source].[StatusInd]
    THEN 
       UPDATE 
          SET [Target].[StartDt] = [Source].[StartDt]       
          .... ----more than 150 columns
          ,[Target].[StatusInd]= [Source].[StatusInd]
```

Comment: which database are you using???

Comment: im using same database for source and target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to spell them out explicitly. But you can generate that code:

```
SELECT
    col.name
    , N'    OR NOT(a.' + QUOTENAME(col.name) + N' = b.' + QUOTENAME(col.name) + N' OR (a.' + QUOTENAME(col.name) + N' IS NULL AND b.' + QUOTENAME(col.name) + N' IS NULL))'
FROM sys.columns col
JOIN sys.objects obj ON col.object_id = obj.object_id
JOIN sys.types tp ON col.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
WHERE obj.name = 'TableNameHere' AND col.is_computed = 0
ORDER BY col.column_id
```

This properly deals with `NULL` values as well. For strings, you should probably add collation clauses to use a binary collation.

Comment: all attributes in both table was set to `NOT NULL` so i dont expect NULL values, is `NOT` statement is better then `<>` ? how about `EXCEPT`, can i use it ?


`Select * from Target` 

`EXCEPT`

`Select * from Source'`

Comment: If NULL is not possible you can use the simpler `<>` idea, yes. I don't see how you could use `EXCEPT` because `MERGE` requires a join condition.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you sure you need to compare all columns on a merge? Can't you simply UPDATE all columns of [Target] with [Source] data whenever `[Target].Key = [Source].Key`, since [Source] contains the good/new values?
- Clever use of text editor features, particularly what's usually called column mode editing, should help you build your SQL statement around a list of column names, one per line (which can be usually extracted from existing SQL statements with even more clever text editing).

Comment: actually what result i need is the same in 3rd party tool called table difference which the output are insert, delete and update, update by comparing each attributes